# the path of html file in apk android app

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, path

i have an android app that works fine in my emulator using eclipse adt.
this app is a hybrid app with html5,js.. so i'm working with the webview .

with this code :

```
browser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/home.html");
```

it works fine in the emulator but outside it gives me file://androidassests doesn't exists .

and i know it's true but what should i put so i can put it in the google play store ?
knowing that the home.html is in the assets folder in the android project .

Comment: What do you mean by outside? On a phone or a browser?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are saying about the warning in ADT DDMS window. If all things work fine in the app and emulator, you don't need to worry about that warning.

Comment: every thing works fine. so if i keepts the path :
file:///android_asset/home.html it will work fine when i will put it in the google store .???

Comment: If your app works fine, all is fine. You can go ahead.